# Use lm object for calculations

Tags: r, linear-regression

I want to use my fit to predict:

```
> fit <- lm(c(3008, 10717) ~ c(69, 247))
> 69 * coef(fit)[2] + coef(fit)[1]
c(69, 247) 
      3008 
>
```

Is there a simpler way requiring less code e.g.

```
> use_lm(fit, 69)
3008
```

Comment: Take a look at `?predict.lm`

Comment: Or, instead of using a linear regression for just two points, you could use [`approxfun`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/approxfun.html) to produce a function that will linearly interpolate between the points.

Comment: I would go with the following: `fit <- lm(y ~ x, data.frame(y = c(3008, 10717), x = c(69, 247)));predict(fit, data.frame(x = 69))`

Comment: my dude is if predict calculate the model AGAIN when is invoked. Another question is why the fit$model is carried over the rest of the code. The model had been estimated previously, so no need to carry in predict nor a function like
`do_prediction(
  data = head(df), 
  lm_object_terms = formula(fit)
)`